# Printing does not work on a Sharp MX 2310U

Tags: printing

Help please with a little printer probem.

I am using a Sharp-MX-2310U printer on the network with Ubuntu 12.10.  Followed all the normal setup and looking at cups `localhost:631/printers/` I see the printer but no print jobs are printed and `/var/spool/cups` just keeps on filling with unfinished jobs.

The printer properties display the ink status etc so I do have connection to the printer but `localhost:631/printers/` shows:

> SHARP-MX-2310U    SHARP MX-2310U  Office  Sharp MX-2300N Foomatic/pxlcolor
>   (recommended) Idle - "Waiting for printer to finish."

Looking in `localhost:631/admin/log/error_log` I get a number of errors but nothing that is obvious.

```
    E [08/Jan/2013:10:31:26 +0000] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
    E [08/Jan/2013:10:31:26 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    E [08/Jan/2013:11:22:41 +0000] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
    E [08/Jan/2013:15:51:29 +0000] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
    E [08/Jan/2013:15:52:43 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    W [08/Jan/2013:15:53:22 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
    W [08/Jan/2013:15:53:22 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
    W [08/Jan/2013:15:54:04 +0000] [Job 1] The printer is unreachable at this time.
    W [08/Jan/2013:15:54:27 +0000] [Job 1] The printer is unreachable at this time.
    W [08/Jan/2013:15:54:40 +0000] [Job 1] The printer is unreachable at this time.
    E [08/Jan/2013:15:54:55 +0000] [Job 1] The printer is not responding.
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:08:22 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:09:40 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:11:33 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:13:38 +0000] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:14:21 +0000] [cups-driverd] Bad driver information file "/usr/share/cups/drv/cupsfilters.drv"!
    W [08/Jan/2013:16:14:45 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
    W [08/Jan/2013:16:14:45 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
    E [08/Jan/2013:16:28:03 +0000] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
    W [08/Jan/2013:16:28:04 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
    W [08/Jan/2013:16:28:04 +0000] AddProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod:No such interface `org.freedesktop.ColorManager' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_SHARP_MX_2310U
```

Comment: Where did you get the driver?

Comment: When I install the printer the wizard asks me to select from a list.  So I guess the driver is bundled with the Ubuntu release in some way.  I also tried the driver found at http://www.sharp.co.uk/cps/rde/xchg/gb/hs.xsl/-/html/product-details.htm?product=MX2310U.  After the install I removed the old printer and re-installed with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue except I have a Canon 1023N over ethernet. I have same errors. It looks like a known bug with cups. Lots of reports coming in now:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1053443

I wish I had known before I went and installed 12.10 as supposedly 12.04 does not have this problem.